# Use 3rd party user's (non-google accounts) with Google Drive Realtime API?

Tags: authentication, google-drive-realtime-api

Can the google drive realtime api be used with a custom user database (non-google users) to manipulate a JSON object. I.e. similar way to firebase?

If so, could you please provide recommendations on an authentication/authorization strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all users must have Google accounts.